# JMeter - CSV Data Set Config- blank variable on 2nd iteration

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have a plan with a CSV Data Set Config element in my thread group.  The CSV has 1 row in it.  Recycle on EOF=true, Stop on EOF=false.

My thread group has 1 thread with loop count=2.
There is a single http request in my thread group that uses a variable assigned in CSV Data Set Config.

My problem:  The http request succeeds the 1st loop iteration, but fails the 2nd time.  It appears the variable from the CSV is blank on the 2nd iteration.

I read over several stack overflow posts on the subject, but couldn't figure it out.

I must be misunderstanding something.

Any insight or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  CSV input file had an extra, blank line at the end.

Stupidly obvious.  sorry to distract and waste your time.